# How to redirect stderr and stdout to more than one output file?

Tags: linux, shell, redirect

I want to know how to write 3 commands for:

- Redirect the output from stdout to file output.txt
- Redirect the output from stderr to file error.txt
- Redirect the output from both stdout and stderr to file all.txt

That is the code I have so far but it doesn't output anything:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    echo This goes to stdout
    echo And this is and error going to stderr 1>&2
    exec 1>output.txt
    exec 2>error.txt
    exec >all.txt 1>&2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with `tee` command in combination of [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3> all.txt # fd3 goes to all.txt
exec 1> >(tee output.txt >&3) # fd1(stdout) goes to both output.txt and fd3
exec 2> >(tee error.txt >&3) # fd2(stderr) goes to both error.txt and fd3

echo Go To Stdout # goes to fd1, and fd1 goes to both output.txt and fd3 (which goes to all.txt)
echo Go To Stderr >&2 # goes to fd2, and fd2 goes to both error.txt and fd3 (which goes to all.txt)
```